# Xamarin Editor interfering with other controls on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, editor

I have a data entry form with an Editor that infringes on an entry below it after it has 2 full lines of text entered (42 characters in this case).

The Editor needs to be able to expand as the user types multiple lines of text. The max length is not set and the user could enter over 100 characters depending on the situation.

The problem is when the first character is typed on the 3rd line (45th character) the entry below it, entInitials, becomes inaccessible (The control will not accept focus).
When I backspace so that there is only 2 lines of text, it become accessible.

The controls are in a grid inside a ViewCell and what I have below is my latest attempt to solve this.

I arrived at this problem when trying to solve my original problem. I generally like to put each of my controls (label & entry control) inside their own Grid inside a ViewCell. But when the Editor control expanded due to multiple lines it would cover the controls in the ViewCell below it (if you can help on that issue I'm open to suggestions). This is only a problem on iOS; on the Android the expanding Editor/ViewCell would push the ViewCell below it further down the screen.

My attempt as seen below was to put the Editor and the initials entry into the same grid. By appearance on the simulator the expanding editor does push the entry down but ultimately makes it inaccessible.

What I haven't shown but is still a problem is any container below the Editor container (Table Section, ViewCell & etc) will be covered or made inaccessible if the Editor expands too many lines.
All help is welcomed, thanks.

The form is set up like this:

```
       <ScrollView>
        <TableView Intent="Data" HasUnevenRows="true" Margin="10,0,10,0">
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat='{0:MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm}'}" Style="{StaticResource LabelDate}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label Text="Instructions" Style="{StaticResource LabelEntry}"/>
                        <Editor x:Name="fcInstructions" Placeholder="Instructions" Focused="EditorHighlight" Unfocused="EditorHighlight" 
                                Style="{StaticResource EditorMessage}" />

                        <StackLayout x:Name="stkInit" BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                     Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label x:Name="lblInits" Text="User Initials:" Style="{StaticResource LabelEntry}"/>
                            <Entry x:Name="entInitials" Focused="EntryHighlightInit" Unfocused="EntryHighlightInit" 
                                   Style="{StaticResource EntryInitials}"/>                                       
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
```

The editor is styled in my global resources like this:

```
        <Style x:Key="EditorMessage" TargetType="Editor">
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="AutoSize" Value="TextChanges"/>
            <Setter Property="Keyboard" Value="Default"/>
            <Setter Property="Placeholder" Value="Message"/>
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="local:KeyboardStyle.KeyboardFlags"
                    Value="Suggestions,CapitalizeCharacter"/>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Sorry that I cannot reproduce actually. And see your UI you don't have to put a grid or stacklayout in a tableview. Just  like ToolmakerSteve said, a grid is okay for all the control. Also, you could consider using ListView or CollectionView if you want to display a list of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin sometimes has problems performing dynamic layout, given nested layouts.

While the appearance may not be exactly what you want, as a test try doing the entire layout using ONLY one Grid, and some Horizontal StackLayouts.

No TableView. No nesting of layouts that affect vertical positions. No Vertical StackLayouts (I don't think you had any).

Also, for clarity, don't set Grid.Row etc properties in the style. Set them directly in the editor (fcElements). This makes it easier to change grid rows or columns, without having to remember to go elsewhere to alter a style. Note that I have changed fcElements Grid.Row below.

The vertical layout would thus be done entirely with Grid.Row (and perhaps Grid.RowSpan):

```xml
<ScrollView>
  <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,30,Auto,5,40" ColumnDefinitions="*,*" ...>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now} ..." ... />

    <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Instructions" ... />
    <Editor Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="fcInstructions" ... />

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="stkInit" Orientation="Horizontal" ... >
      ...
    </StackLayout>
  </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

If this works, it might be a starting point for getting the exact look you want.

---

**UPDATE: Alternative Solution**

I just realized the problem might be something completely different.

The original height of ScrollView, TableView, and TableViewSection did not include space for expansion.

After your 4 RowDefinitions, include this one:

```xml
  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
```

This will cause the Grid to expand vertically to the bottom of the screen.

At first nothing will be in that space, but it will give room for expansion.

Its likely a bug in ScrollView, perhaps combined with TableView.

Comment: thanks for the assistance. Based on your suggestions I tried a few options starting with removing the TableView and the ViewCells. The one I settled on was a series of Grids inside a StackLayout inside the ScrollView. This way I could maintain the relation ship between the entry control (Entry, Editor, Picker) and the label that decorates it. I have about 20 of these entry forms and this will help with the symmetry between them. FYI - This is the reason I put the rows & columns in the Style so that all entry forms will have a consistent look & feel)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the Nesting of the layout controls. I removed the TableView & the ViewCells  and used a series of Grids. Now the Auto height of the Instructions Editor adjust properly on the screen and doesn't cover or infringe on the other controls below it.

```
          <ScrollView>
          <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat='{0:MMMM d, yyyy HH:mm}'}" Style="{StaticResource LabelDate}" />
            </StackLayout>

            <Grid Padding="10,0,10,0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Text="Requestor" TextColor="Black" Style="{StaticResource LabelEntry}"/>
            <Label Text="" x:Name="User" Style="{StaticResource LabelEntry}" Grid.Column="1" TextTransform="Uppercase"/>
            </Grid>

            <Grid Padding="10,0,10,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
               </Grid.RowDefinitions>                        
               <Label Text="Instructions" Style="{StaticResource LabelEntry}"/>
              <Editor x:Name="fcInstructions" Placeholder="Instructions" Focused="EditorHighlight" Unfocused="EditorHighlight" 
                                Style="{StaticResource EditorMessage}" />
         </Grid>
```